# How to show toast on a fragment in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, toast

I am not able to show a toast on a fragment. It shows the error as in the screenshot. I am using `kotlin`. Please advice.

[image]

Error message

[image]

Comment: Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: I think it will resolve the issue as I can't see any errors. But I cannot confirm as my toasts are not been shown. However, it could be because of any other issue which I have asked about in another post in details. Could you look at that also?
And, add this comment as an answer here so that I can mark it as the Answer to this question.

Comment: My other question is here... https://stackoverflow.com/q/67860090/13935956

Comment: Please add your comment as the Answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Use Fragment's `activity`. You can use extension function to easily produce toasts in fragments:

```
fun Fragment.makeToast(text: String,duration: Int = Toast.LENGTH_LONG) {
    activity?.let {
        Toast.makeText(it, text, duration).show()
    }
}
```

Now in the Fragment you can just use it like:

```
class LoginFragment : Fragment() {
   //...
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        //...

        makeToast("lets start")
```

Comment: Could you explain how to do it? As a beginner, I don't understand how to do it. Thanks.

This is my fragment.
class OrdersByStatusFragment : BaseFragment() {

}

Comment: I have added a sample into an answer, replies here are too limited.